# Removing worklight server config files for new eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ibm-mobilefirst

I have installed worklight/IBM Mobile first plugin in my eclipse. But I want to enable the worklight server only to specific projects. The issue is, if I create a new eclipse project, the worklight automatically creates the config files in my new eclipse project. I don't want this unnecessary config files to my other projects, only it should be enabled in worklight projects.

I tried deleting the worklight server in server view and deleted files from folders, but when I restart the eclipse, it is again creating the config files.
Is there anyway to disable worklight in eclipse in default?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to untick the Project >> Build automatically option, but I doubt this will help and even if it will help it is not recommended to untick it as it is needed.

The other option would of course to use another Eclipse instance where you do not have the MobileFirst Studio plug-in installed.